# Seeing line number

Tags: two-column, lineno

I am writing a paper with double column. When I use `\packages{lineno}` and `\linenumbers`, it shows every line of each column.

I just want to see line numbers on the left of empty space. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what you mean by "see line number on the left of empty space". Also, did you mean to write `\usepackage{lineno}` instead of `\packages{lineno}`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.